# "System.AccessViolationException" coming randomly after VC++ project migrated to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

After I migrated VC++ 2010 projects to Visual studio 2015 ,we are getting below error randomly when we run code on windows server 2008.

`Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException`

As part of migration we made below settings to VCProjects

1. Platform toolset : Visual Studio 2015 (v140)
2. Target Platform version : 8.1
3. Multi-Processor compilation : No

Comment: Maybe your migration uncovered a hidden bug that your code always had.  No way to give you any more information than that.

Comment: The same code run well without any issues , since last few years, when its build with Visual studio 2010. And even this issue is getting appeared randomly for same code  on our application server.

Comment: Maybe compiling with warning level 4 or running a static analyzer can help to find some undefined behaviors that can cause the crash.

Comment: I dont think anyone can answer this with 100% certainty with the information you've given, but undefined behavior is a likely candidate.

Comment: I dont have much exposure with VC++ , let me know what more information will be required , I can add it.

Comment: @Priyang *The same code run well without any issues , since last few years,* --  My comment said *hidden bugs*, meaning that your program never exposed them, but now the new environment does.   Things like buffer overruns and similar errors can exist in programs for years without anyone noticing them -- it is only when the program is ported to a new environment or compiler does it become noticed.